# No Data Returned on VB Report

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I'm new to VB so please don't laugh too loudly at my coding skills :)

I have created a dataset (Dataset1) that pulls from 2 tables. The SQL on the table adapter joins the 2 tables. The table adapters all return data correctly. The data sources on the report viewer are:

```
 DataSet1_uaPowderCoat
 DataSet1_uaPowderCoatType
```

and they are both instantiated to their binding sources. There is a report parameter (Lot Num) that needs to filter the info in the report to data from one row.

Code in the form load event:

```
 Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1_uaPowderCoat", uaPowderCoatTableAdapter.GetData()))
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1_uaPowderCoatType", UaPowderCoatTypeTableAdapter.GetData()))
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

And in the report event:

```
  Dim params(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
        params(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Report_Parameter_0", Me.txtLotNumber.Text)

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
        Me.uaPowderCoatTableAdapter.FillByPCLotNbr(DataSet1.uaPowderCoat, me.txtLotNumber.Text)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Report Fields are:
=Parameters!Report_Parameter_0.Value

=(Fields!PCStrength.Value)

The Parameter field works fine, but I can't get the rest of the fields to populate (just #error). I have researched and tried a ton of different things and if I get one thing fixed something else goes wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post error message and stack trace.

Comment: Oh, sorry! There is no error message, just #error in the report fields. I see this warning: Warning: The Value expression for the textbox ‘PCStrength’ contains an error: The expression referenced a non-existing field in the fields collection. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Comment: I don't know how to get the stack trace.

Comment: Why is it saying non-existent field? did you use the expression builder thingy to build that?

Comment: I dragged the field from the field list on the data sources window. When I do that it attaches an aggregate to it (=SUM(Fields!PCStrength.Value)). That flagged an error so I removed the SUM.

Comment: Also as a side issue you might look at using a JOIN in your query and also passing the Lot Num parameter to the query. That way you are potentially pulling back a whole lot less data, and you only have one result set and datasource to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a data source binding error or a syntax error in the field. Try one of the following:

- For data source bindings, make sure the bindingSource and DataSources are both connected to the report and also the report has access to them. Heres how I bind my data sources:

  `this.bindingSource1.DataSource = somelist;`
  `this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SomeDataTableName", (this.PointBindingSource)));`
- Also, I noticed the difference in DataSet name in `DataSet1_uaPowderCoat` and `FillByPCLotNbr(DataSet1.uaPowderCoat`. That could be the error?
- Make sure `=Parameters!Report_Parameter_0.Value =(Fields!PCStrength.Value)` is the correct syntax. Are you missing an `IFF` statement?